# JBoss WS Temp file saved incorrectly

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jbossws

My [problem from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158923/jboss-webservice-npe) is say sorted. Not solved though.

The NPE I had was triggered by a FileNotFoundException that was hidden until I switched to TRACE logging (org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver)...

So here is the thing:
1.) I'm trying to connect to the webservice from code that is deployed to under JBoss
2.) JBossWs saves the wsdl to the **tmp** folder like this:

```
file:/home/xxx/dev/XXXX/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/yyy/tmp/jbossws/JBossWS_www.company.xx_99_server_soap.php?wsdl=get8489235369016302536.xsd
```

3.) And then when it tries to read back the WSDL:

```
TRACE [org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver] Failed to obtain URL.InputStream from systemId: file:/home/xxx/dev/xxx-PAN/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/xxxxxxx/tmp/jbossws/JBossWS_www.comany.xx_99_server_soap.php?wsdl=get8489235369016302536.xsd
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/xxx/dev/xxx-PAN/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/xxxxxxx/tmp/jbossws/JBossWS_www.comany.xx_99_server_soap.php
```

Obviously it truncates and then not able to read back.

I guess I would be able to configure somehow the pattern how it writes it to disk or how it reads it back but I did find the solution (even not from the code of the JBoss class I mentioned). Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I created a simple test application on the Linux server pointing to the same file containing the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("file:/home/abos/xxx/xxxx/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/xxxxxxx/tmp/jbossws/JBossWS_www.company.xx_99_server_soap.php?wsdl=get8489235369016302536.xsd");
    url.openStream();

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/xxx/dev/xxxx/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/anchorage/tmp/jbossws/JBossWS_www.bdmglobal.xx_99_server_soap.php (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

So here are my conclusions:
1.) Actually it is the URL class that truncates the name
2.) But if it was saved properly it would not be a problem.

So I'm still looking for a way to configure that.

Comment: Here is my original post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158923/jboss-webservice-npe

Answer (score 1):

never saw this problem so my answer may won't help you much....
Have you tried to set the jboss.server.temp.dir property to something like /tmp and run your test case again ? There may be some hardcoded length and trying to shorten the path may solve the problem ...
Another trick would be to setup a .sar Jboss service requesting your wsdl and publishing them through JNDI to avoid all problems with path ffrom the client point of view ? You just have to handle a stream and put it into the JNDI tree ..no path involved

If your problem occurs when JBoss **saves the file** so not saving it would solve your problem isn't it ? That 's why I suggest to grab the wsdl as a stream (or text using Reader or InputStream as you prefer) and to put it directly into your JNDI tree....
HTH
Jerome

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for answering. So i just tried to resolve it with the temp folder change. No luck there, at least i learned to tweak that also. Thanks.

Comment: I will now try to see if i can implement your second suggestion. I'm not sure i get the big picture so let me see if i can do that :)

Comment: Hi, the big picture would be to setup a Jboss service (deployed as .sar) grabbing your wsdl directly as streams and putting these streams into the JNDI  Tree using the naming convention of your choice... Finding them for your clients would be easy , just a standard JNDI invokation (with all Jboss standard properties)...It should work...

Comment: Wow. Now i get it. Thanks i will try to implement this in the afternoon and revert.

Comment: I think i'm stuck that way as well. The reason is that no matter how i configure the service client stub (giving it the wsdl and a QName for the service or only the wsdl so the generated service contains the url) it is not problematic there.

The problem occurs when JBossWS saves the service contract to a file and trying to read it back. And this happening only when the WS implementation is trying to build up the connection. So i think even  if the WSDL would be retrieve from JNDI.